# How to loop through the value of a object key compare it to another value if match than change it to another value

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have nested object named `userGraph`:

```
var userGraph ={
    Book: {copyBook: 2, brownBook: 3},
    Shoes: {whiteshoes: 3, blackshoes: 4}
}
```

I want to loop over the  value of  all the keys of my `userGraph` object. If any key matches 'copyBook' then I want to change that key to something else like 'blackBook' so the new Object will look like

```
var userGraph ={
   Book: {blackBook: 2, brownBook: 3},
   Shoes: {whiteShoes: 3, blackShoes: 4}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over all the values and use the `delete` operator.

```js
var userGraph = {
  Book: {copyBook:2,brownBook:3},
  Shoes: {whiteshoes:3, blackshoes:4}
};
let remove = 'copyBook', replace = 'blackBook';
for(const o of Object.values(userGraph)){
  if(remove in o){
    o[replace] = o[remove];
    delete o[remove];
  }
}
console.log(userGraph);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var userGraph ={
Book:{copyBook:2,brownBook:3},
Shoes:{whiteshoes:3, blackshoes:4}
}
for (var key in userGraph) {              
     for (var key2 in userGraph[key]) {
       if(key2 == 'copyBook'){
           userGraph[key]['blackBook']=userGraph[key][key2];
           delete userGraph[key][key2];}
  }
}
console.log(userGraph);
```